# Question regarding quotient of small submodules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I came across an equivalence about quotient of small modules, that I would love to prove or if someone can tell if my attempt of proving it, is correct. Recall that $S$ is a small submodule of $M$ if for every submodule $N \leq M$ such that $S + N = M$ we obtain that $N=M$. Now let's go to the crux of the matter.

Let's  have $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are submodules of $M$ such that $S_{1} \subseteq S_{2}$.Then,  $S_{2} \leq_s M $ if and only if $S_{1} \leq_s M$ and $\frac{S_{2}}{S_{1}} \leq_{s} \frac{M}{S_{1}}$.

Let´s assume $S_{2} \leq_s M $. First, in order to prove $S_{1} \leq_s M$. So take a submodule $N \leq M$ such that $S_{1} + N = M$. Since $S_{1} \subseteq S_{2}$ by our general assumption, we obtain $S_{2} + N = M$, so it follows from the "smallness" of $S_{2}$ in $M$ that $N = M$ whence $S_{1} \leq _{s} M$ as required.  Now I would like to prove that $\frac{S_{2}}{S_{1}} \leq_{s} \frac{M}{S_{1}}$, so by choosing a random submodule $\frac{N}{ S_{1}}$ of $\frac{M}{S_{1}}$ such that $\frac{N}{ S_{1}} + \frac{S_{2}}{ S_{1}} = \frac{M}{ S_{1}}$. We strive to prove that $\frac{N}{ S_{1}} = \frac{M}{ S_{1}}$. By our assumming $\frac{N}{ S_{1}} + \frac{S_{2}}{ S_{1}} = \frac{M}{ S_{1}}$ we obtain $S_{1} + N = M$ (I'm not sure if this step is right and if so, why this is correct??). Therefore, by the "smallness" of $S_{1}$ in $M$ we obtain $N=M$. Proving that $\frac{N}{ S_{1}} = \frac{M}{ S_{1}}$.

On the other hand, we want to prove that $S_{2} \leq_{s} M$. That is, for every $N \leq M$ such that $N + S_{2} = M$ we need to show that $N=M$. But since $S_{1} \leq S_{2}$ we obtain $N + S_{1} = M$ and this implies $N=M$ because $S_{1} \leq_{s} M$. I'm doubtful in this implication since I hadn't use the assumption of $\frac{S_{2}}{S_{1}} \leq_{s} \frac{M}{S_{1}}$

Comment: The converse is not quite correct. Take $N$ with $N+S_2=M$. Set $U:=(N+S_1)/S_1$. Then $U+S_2/S_1=M/S_1$, so $U=M/S_1$, i.e. $N+S_1=M$. Since $S_1$ is small, we get $N=M$.

Comment: @AndrewHubery Thanks! Do you think all my proof but the part you commented is OK?

Comment: It’s basically correct, but you probably need to read over your notes on the isomorphism theorems. In the first part you choose some $N/S_1$ inside $M/S_1$ with $N/S_1+S_2/S_1=M/S_1$. Taking preimages in $M$, we have $S_1\subseteq N\subseteq M$ with $N+S_2=M$, and not $N+S_1=M$ as you wrote.